# it there any way to reset device in (slimdx, dx9) without disposing all device-related objects?

Tags: resize, directx-9, slimdx

I am rendering using SlimDX to a control in a form. Since the size of that control might change very often, and there are lots of complex meshes, the traditional free-reset-construct method may be too slow to my taste. Any way to boost it up?

Answer (score 1):

create an additional SwapChain linked to your current window using IDirect3DDevice9::CreateAdditionalSwapChain Method,

then, get the back buffer of the new SwapChain, and, use IDirect3DDevice9::SetRenderTarget method
to set the back buffer of the new SwapChain as the render target,

when you finished your drawings, call the present method of the new SwapChain instead of the IDirect3DDevice9::present,

when your window is resized, just release the additional SwapChain and re-create it with new back buffer sizes and do the render target setting thing again, now, you don`t have to do the device reset which is very slow.

if you have any more questions, email me : xux660@hotmail.com

I am a chinese so my english is not so good, forgive me.